# How to use special characters in C?

Tags: c, internationalization

I realized that my program has to be able to handle special characters such as Japanese or Chinese. But I know the built-in type `char` is far from enough. So how can I use these special characters in C program?

Comment: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [wide characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character).

They're what you need for Unicode, they can get work with pretty much every character you throw it at, and it can do that because -- and this is the catch: it consumes more bytes (twice as much; it sounds tons but for the most part, it's really not).

Note:
In Windows programming you use the `TEXT("")` macro to choose whether your characters will be Unicode or ANSI. it'll choose according to your project's setting.
If you insist to have it Unicode you can write the string with a prefix of the `L` letter like so: `L"Unicode String"`

The header file to work with wide-characters is `wchar.h`.

Comment: setlocale(LC_ALL,""); What does this line do?

Comment: @user1229490 Here's a reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/clocale/setlocale/

Comment: Don't forget to consider utf-8. That way you don't need wide characters.

Comment: @Matt Do you mean something like UTF8-CPP or something else by a third-party?

Comment: @Ken utf-8 is inherently supported by anything that uses 8-bit char values.

Answer (score 5):

like this in windows VS :)

```
#include <tchar.h>
typedef struct _我的结构{
    int 数据;
    TCHAR 字符串指针[100];
}我的结构;
int main(int argc,char** argv){
    我的结构 我的变量 = {1, _T("字符串123abc")};
    _tprintf(_T("%s, %d"),我的变量.字符串指针,我的变量.字符串指针);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use UTF-8 encoding if you could live with the fact that one byte != one unicode character.

Comment: It uses the same unicode character table. UTF8 uses a variable length encoding. Every PHP developer has to deal with this btw ;)

Answer (score 2):

for unicode type languages,  you can use wchar_t instead of char

Comment: do I need any header file? and is there anything need to be noticed?

Comment: yes, you need to be very aware that you are using wchar_t,  there's a rich library of functions, etc,  like wstring  etc.  You will need to look up the documentation so you understand how to deal with them, how to declare string literals, etc.